# check NULL value and insert other column value in SQL*LOADER ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-loader

Below is the control file we used to load the data in table. The scenario is like, if COLUMN6 is NULL then use/insert COLUMN4 value while load the data into the table. Is it feasible through SQL*Loader. Have searched multiple place but not get the required details. Please assist me.

```
OPTIONS (ROWS=1000, READSIZE=2097152, BINDSIZE=2097152, PARALLEL=TRUE)
LOAD DATA
INFILE '{INFILE}'
APPEND

INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME
WHEN
FEED='FEED'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
COLUMN1  POSITION(1) DECIMAL EXTERNAL,
COLUMN2  CHAR(5),
COLUMN3  CHAR(11),
COLUMN4  CHAR(10),
COLUMN5  CHAR(30),
COLUMN6  CHAR(30)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
COLUMN6  CHAR(30) "NVL(:COLUMN6,:COLUMN4)"
```

?